# Android: How to work with background thread?

Tags: android, multithreading, background

I've developed an application that takes content from the internet and shows it accordingly on the device's screen . The program works just fine , a little bit slow . It takes about 3-4 seconds to load and display the content . I would like to put all the code that fetches the content and displays it in a background thread and while the program is doing those functions , I would like to display a progress dialog. Could you help me do this ? I would like especially to learn how to put the code in a background thread.

**MY CODE**

```
public class Activity1 extends Activity
{
    private ProgressDialog progressDialog;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        new AsyncTask<Integer, Integer, Boolean>()
        {
            ProgressDialog progressDialog;

            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute()
            {
                /*
                 * This is executed on UI thread before doInBackground(). It is
                 * the perfect place to show the progress dialog.
                 */
                progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(Activity1.this, "",
                        "Loading...");
            }

            @Override
            protected Boolean doInBackground(Integer... params)
            {
                if (params == null)
                {
                    return false;
                }
                try
                {
                    /*
                     * This is run on a background thread, so we can sleep here
                     * or do whatever we want without blocking UI thread. A more
                     * advanced use would download chunks of fixed size and call
                     * publishProgress();
                     */
                    Thread.sleep(params[0]);
                    // HERE I'VE PUT ALL THE FUNCTIONS THAT WORK FOR ME
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    Log.e("tag", e.getMessage());
                    /*
                     * The task failed
                     */
                    return false;
                }

                /*
                 * The task succeeded
                 */
                return true;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result)
            {
                progressDialog.dismiss();
                /*
                 * Update here your view objects with content from download. It
                 * is save to dismiss dialogs, update views, etc., since we are
                 * working on UI thread.
                 */
                AlertDialog.Builder b = new AlertDialog.Builder(Activity1.this);
                b.setTitle(android.R.string.dialog_alert_title);
                if (result)
                {
                    b.setMessage("Download succeeded");
                }
                else
                {
                    b.setMessage("Download failed");
                }
                b.setPositiveButton(getString(android.R.string.ok),
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
                        {

                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dlg, int arg1)
                            {
                                dlg.dismiss();
                            }
                        });
                b.create().show();
            }
        }.execute(2000);

        new Thread()
        {
            @Override
            public void run()
            {

                // dismiss the progressdialog
                progressDialog.dismiss();
            }
        }.start();
    }
}
```

Comment: Where are you getting the null pointer? (The screenshot isn't loading for me.) Also, what is the purpose of the second thread  that just has `progressDialog.dismiss()`?

Comment: I think your Thread.sleep call is throwing an exception. And the exception has no message so e.getMessage() returns null.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Check [ASyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html), its specifically created for such tasks.

Comment: +1 ASync task is the way to go. It allows you to update the UI thread from a background thread.

Comment: so I'm told .. If you could tell me what's wrong with my code ( in my question) you'll definetely get the vote... if I use it , the application crashes

Comment: First off, I'd remove the Thread object at the bottom since it's not doing anything.

Comment: my guess is that the new Thread() stuff at the bottom is causing the null pointer.

Answer (score 5):

```
public Runnable NameOfRunnable = new Runnable()
{
    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            // TODO add code to refresh in background
            try
            {
                Thread.sleep(1000);// sleeps 1 second
            }
            catch (InterruptedException e)
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    }
};
```

now start this with

```
                    Thread name = new Thread(NameOfRunnable);
                    name.start();
```

Comment: This thread cannot do anything on the UI thread so it is pointless to mention this. He needs to be able to talk to the UI thread in order to update the progress dialog. Async task is the way to go.

Comment: Depends on how you setup your activity. Check out the Handler class for interacting with the UI

Answer (score 2):

How to **work** with **Background Thread**.

#### Note:

**Do not work with UI** with this **background thread**.

```
AsyncTask.execute(new Runnable() {
   @Override
   public void run() {
      //TODO background code
   }
});
```

Hope this would help you.

Comment: This is a perfect solution